# InDesign CS5 Numbered Lists Not Incremeneting Properly

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am trying to create a paragraph style for number lists. Pretty basic, just some customized indents etc. But each item in my list is not sequentially numbered, i.e., each item within a list starts is numbered 1.

If I select Start With Previous, Each item within a list increments properly.  But of course, then all of the lists are linked and each list starts at n+1: where n is where the last one ended.

Please advise.

Comment: Please read about [merging accounts](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). If you use the account that owns this question, you can comment on any answer (which is what you should do if you want to request clarification).

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I understood well.

Even checking **Restart Numbering** or **Continue Numbering** from the **Paragraph Panel Options** to the selected paragraph doesn't help?

[image: LIST ANIMATION]

[image: paragraph panel]

Comment: [This is what my Paragraphs Panel Option looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeDc1.png)

Comment: The changing at the animation is from the **Paragraph Panel Options** not from the **Paragraph Style Options**

Comment: Where do I find that? Which menu or dropdown is it in? Please keep in mind I am using CS5.

Comment: Ok, there are two Paragraph Windows: **Paragraph Panel** and **Paragraph Style**. InDesign has this since version 1. Forget about the Paragraph Style and go to the "regular" paragraph panel.

Comment: Went to the regular Paragraph Panel. For each list item, I had to chose Continue Numbering. It worked. But it can't be that hard for every list?

Comment: That depends on each case, I do not know exactly how is your text. Another option is to create two different paragraph styles for each kind of list.

Comment: @MLDuBrow How could it be easier? InDesign has no way of knowing whether something is the next item in an existing list or the first item in a new list? Unless you have multi-level lists (where you can restart numbering after an item in a higher-level list), there’s no way to tell the two apart.